# my custom answer box not working like in the windows livecode

Tags: mobile, dialog, popup, livecode

Hi Is there a way that my custom answer/ask box will appear the same on a smartphone? It was deployed on every screen on the phone and did not look like a computer (I used a substack)

Comment: Can you add some code or a screenshot? Currently, your question is very unclear. Nobody can guess how your custom dialog box is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile phones OS are as a single stack, no way to show other stacks. So any answer dialogue is the OS standard style.

Otherwise ask to http://ekkotek.com/index.php/products/livecode-tools/wheelib

The developed custom gui for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

In mobile systems, the stacks always occupy the entire screen space. So if you want to use a custom answer.

You must simulate a floating window using a group.
Try creating a group with all the substack controls you already have. Now instead of calling the substack, what you should do is show and hide the group.
Create a graph inside the group and before making this group visible, establish the rectangel of this graph to the rectangel of the current card. Then put your dialog window in the center and in this way you will have a floating and personalized window.